# Reactive my iPhone5

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5 was stolen and I erased and removed it via iCloud.

After three days I found it and want to active it again.

What is the procedure for recovering the content and activating it again?

also when I turn on the devise a massage as below is appeared:

"your iPhone could not be activated because the activation server is temporarily unavailable. try connection your iPhone to activate it, or try again in couple of minute"
 I tried times and times but it doesn't work.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

To reactive your phone you should introduce a SIM Card connected to internet, plug it to iTunes then try to reactive it until Apple won't restore his server (try in a couple of hours...), it should ask you your Apple ID password.

To recover the content you can restore it from backup.